# C++ GDIPlus Bitmap lockbits results WrongState(8)

Tags: c++, gdi+, gdi

I'm trying to get rect. of diffent area between two Bitmap* objects.   When i pass 2 bitmap* it can run lockbits for first frame but it cannot do it for second bitmap.

```
 Rect GetRecDifference(Bitmap* currentFrame, Bitmap* previousFrame) {
if (previousFrame == NULL) {
    previousFrame = currentFrame;

}
else {
    return Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

BitmapData* bd1 = new BitmapData;
Rect rect1(0, 0, currentFrame->GetWidth(), currentFrame->GetHeight());
currentFrame->LockBits(&rect1, ImageLockModeRead, PixelFormat32bppARGB, bd1);

BitmapData* bd2 = new BitmapData;
Rect rect2(0, 0, previousFrame->GetWidth(), previousFrame->GetHeight());
previousFrame->LockBits(&rect2, ImageLockModeRead, PixelFormat32bppARGB, bd2);
```

It can run for first one (bd1*) load status ok and last result is shows ok. but when it comes to bd2 it shows status as WrongState(8).

Is this because i copy current pointer to previous one ? What's reason can be for wrong state error ? Do i need to clear some parts from memory ?

Comment: Why to you have two pointers pointing at the same bitmap? Why are you trying to lock the same bitmap twice? I guess that's why it isn't working.

Comment: Hello, i want to have current bitmap check it against previous bitmap and after it's finished i save current bitmap as previous bitmap. Hmm.You may be right. i will quickly check that. What about copying current frame to previous frame part ? i mean how should i do it ? is simply previous = current enough or i should clone image to previous variable because as you know i must delete current image at the end of function.

Comment: `previous = current` makes both pointers point at the same bitmap.

Comment: hmm after i do previous = current and i do delete current so it points to same direction which is nothing :) am i right ? thank you so much for quick responses by the way.

Comment: If you delete the current image at the end of the function there there is no way to use it as the previous image the next time you call the function. Seems to me that you should delete the previous image at the end of the function, then assign the current image pointer to previous. Then right at the end after you've finished calling this function you should do a final delete on the last previous image. But I am kind of speculating.

Comment: i see my current logic goes following
current = TakeScreenShot();

Rect changedArea =GetChangedAre(current,previous)

previous = current;

delete current;

i think somehow i need to keep last state of current into previous to compare it in next cycle.

Comment: `previous = current` followed by `delete current` just means previous points to a deleted image. Like I said you should *not* delete current if you want to use it on the next iteration. You should be deleting previous instead, so that you always have two valid images at all times.

Comment: actually i don't want to keep current for next iteration because i get new current in every iteration and then compare it with previous. So i always thought that i should delete current (because everytime i will get new one) and keep previous ( because i will need it for next iteration). But from your comments i understood that i'm currently keeping nothing because when i do previous = current and then delete current i lose everything. how can i keep current image correctly for next iteration ?

Comment: Where do you think previous for the next iteration comes from except from current for this iteration? You do want to keep current from this iteration because it will become the previous of the next iteration.

Comment: At the start of each iteration `current = getNewCurrent();` then do stuff with previous and current then at the end of each iteration `delete previous; previous = current;`

Comment: And then finally once the whole iteration has finished you will still have one previous image left over, so one final `delete previous;`.

Comment: Also one the very first iteration there won't be any previous, so you'll have nothing to do. Basically because you are handling two images at once, you've got to delay deleting each image, They only get deleted after they have been a current and a previous image, i,e after two iterations, that's why delete previous is correct.

Comment: I think i understood what you mean. I was putting value then cleaning it. now we clear old one and place new one instead. (current ( which is new previous for next iteration))

Comment: Yep, that sounds about right.

Comment: Yes you are right for first one i just check if previous is NULL then i continue with what i have. Thank you so much. you been really helpful.

Comment: Dear @john i tried to set you comment as answer but i think its not possible. If you post one of you comment as answer i would be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to lock the same image twice, this

```
previousFrame = currentFrame;
```

means that both your pointers are pointing to the same image.

Instead you need a scheme that keeps two images in memory at once. Something like the following

```
Bitmap* current = NULL;
Bitmap* previous = NULL;
while (something)
{
    current = getNextImage(); // get the new image
    if (current && previous)
    {
        // process current and previous images
        ...
    }
    delete previous; // delete the previous image, not needed anymore
    previous = current; // save the current image as the previous
}
delete previous; // one image left over, delete it as well
```

Not the only way to do it, but hopefully you get the idea.